# error: incompatible types: Context cannot be converted to HomeMenu

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

i don't know about this problem, how to resolve this problem this is my fragment code in android studio. maybe get data can't get because something else in frgament or RecycleViewAdapter. because this error to RecycleViewAdapter. class, this is my fragment.

```
    AndroidNetworking.get("http://xxxxxxxx/driverapps/getData.php")
            .setTag("Get Data")
            .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();


                    try{
                        Boolean status = response.getBoolean("status");
                        if(status){
                            JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("result");
                            Log.d("respon",""+ja);
                            for(int i = 0 ; i < ja.length() ; i++){
                                JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                                array_noinduk.add(jo.getString("noinduk"));
                                array_nama.add(jo.getString("nama"));
                                array_alamat.add(jo.getString("alamat"));
                                array_hobi.add(jo.getString("hobi"));
                            }
                            recycleViewAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(getContext(),array_noinduk,array_nama,array_alamat,array_hobi);
                            rv_main.setAdapter(recycleViewAdapter);
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Gagal Mengambil Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            recycleViewAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(getContext(),array_noinduk,array_nama,array_alamat,array_hobi);
                            rv_main.setAdapter(recycleViewAdapter);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
```

this is my RecycleViewAdapter,((HomeMenu)mContext).startActivityForResult(i,2); make me error code from this class, how to resolve this error ?

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.tv_noind.setText(array_noinduk.get(position));
    holder.tv_nama.setText(array_nama.get(position));
    holder.tv_alamat.setText(array_alamat.get(position));
    holder.tv_hobi.setText(array_hobi.get(position));
    holder.cv_main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext,RoomActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("noinduk",array_noinduk.get(position));
            i.putExtra("nama",array_nama.get(position));
            i.putExtra("alamat",array_alamat.get(position));
            i.putExtra("hobi",array_hobi.get(position));
            ((HomeMenu)mContext).startActivityForResult(i,2);
        }
    });

}
```

i don't know how to resolve this problem

Comment: Can you provide the adapter code?

Comment: What is mContext?....it need to be activity context...and r u passing it from the fragment to the adapter? and do not cast it to HomeMenu it is of no use to u.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.tv_noind.setText(array_noinduk.get(position));
    holder.tv_nama.setText(array_nama.get(position));
    holder.tv_alamat.setText(array_alamat.get(position));
    holder.tv_hobi.setText(array_hobi.get(position));
    holder.cv_main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext,RoomActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("noinduk",array_noinduk.get(position));
            i.putExtra("nama",array_nama.get(position));
            i.putExtra("alamat",array_alamat.get(position));
            i.putExtra("hobi",array_hobi.get(position));
            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(i,2);
        }
    });
}
```

HomeMenu cannot cast so instead of same you can add Actvity

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. Could you please add a few words of explanation about what was wrong and how you fixed it? Thanks!